# How to set custom MIME type for application?

Tags: android, android-input-filter

In my app i want to interact with Gmail app. I need to open attached files with custom extension. I try this solution:

```
<data android:mimeType="application/*"
      android:pathPattern=".*\\.mms"
      android:scheme="file" />
<data
      android:mimeType="application/*"
      android:pathPattern=".*\\.mms"
      android:scheme="content" />
```

but it bind my app for all extension. I try to add existing MIME type rule:

```
<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
```

and it is works fine for me. So, how i can add custom MIME type?